# (NodeJs) Drive revision update

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a specific revision from google drive files and update that revision as the latest. But after doing so I'm getting some unformatted text over the sheets as shown in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb9Sr.png). Can someone help with this?
I'm trying to achieve a revision update with a specific revision download as a blob and updating this downloaded version to drive for that file.

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  credentials: { ...Credentials },
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  ],
});
const drive: drive_v2.Drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v2',
  auth,
});
const driveV3: drive_v3.Drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth,
});
const list = await driveV3.revisions.list({
  fileId: process.env.PRODUCTS_SPREAD_SHEET_ID,
});
console.log(list.data.revisions);
const response = await drive.revisions.get({
  fileId: process.env.PRODUCTS_SPREAD_SHEET_ID,
  revisionId: '244',
});
const endPoint =
  response.data.exportLinks[
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  ];
console.log(endPoint);
const apiRes = await makeGetApiCall(
  endPoint,
  { Authorization },
  'blob'
);
```

Here I'm updating the file content that I've downloaded above as blob in variable `apiRes`.

```
const aa = await driveV3.files.update({
  fileId: process.env.PRODUCTS_SPREAD_SHEET_ID,
  media: {
    body: apiRes,
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
  }
});
```

Comment: why are you mixing drive2 and drive3?

Comment: Hi there @shivamm! Please don't mix different API versions in order to prevent compatibility issues. Would you like to have the answer in v2 or v3?